# Focal Length of a Rotating Liquid Mirror

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics, telescopes

I saw this video on YouTube about using rotating liquid metal as parabolic mirrors to make reflecting telescopes.
In the video apart from the standard equation of the curve the liquid makes, the focal length of the mirror so formed was given as
$$f=\frac{g}{2\omega^2}
\\g=acceleration \, due\,to \,gravity\\\omega=angular\,speed\,of\,the\,rotating \,liquid$$
I tried to derive it mathematically but was unsuccessful. It would be great if anyone could give their thoughts on how we arrive at this formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mirror is radially symetric so we can solve this
problem only in two dimensions with two coordinates, namely $z$
(height) and $r$ (distance from the rotation axis). The coordinate
system will be rotating with the mirror. Let us look at the forces
acting on a small element of mercury. Reduced to unit mass, they are

- gravitational acceleration $\vec{a_g}$ pointing down with magnitude $g$;
- centrifugal acceleration $\vec{a_h}$ pointing away from the rotation axis,
  whose magnitude increases linearly with $r$ as $\omega^2 r$.

Their corresponding potentials are $gz$ and $-\frac{1}{2} \omega^2 r^2$ and
total potential is therefore
$$
U(r, z) = gz - \frac{1}{2} \omega^2 r^2.
$$

Mercury will form a shape which has constant potential on the whole surface
(if the potential wasn't constant, mercury would want to move around);
and since potential is defined up to an additive constant,
we can choose it so that the potential is zero on the surface of the mercury.
The shape of the surface is thus given by a line whose explicit equation we can obtain from
$$
gz - \frac{1}{2} \omega^2 r^2 = 0
\Rightarrow
z = \frac{\omega^2}{2g} r^2.
$$

Here we can already recognise a parabola -- now we only need to determine its parameters. All light rays parallel to the axis of the mirror (vertical rays in this problem) will concentrate in one point (which is a pleasant finding given that we are building a telescope). The simplest way to find the focus is to find a ray that will be horizontal after reflecting from the parabola. In the point where this particular ray hits the mirror, the mercury makes a $45°$ angle with the horizontal line and the $z$ coordinate of the point is the same as that of the focus point. Or we can recall that a parabola is a set of points which are at the same distance
from the focus and the directrix; and that in the point where the particular ray hits the mirror we know that $z = f$ and $r = 2f$. Then
$$
f = \frac{\omega^2}{2g} 4 f^2
\Rightarrow
f = \frac{g}{2 \omega^2}.
$$